# VIM loses syntax highlighting when using split command

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

So I have created my own syntax highlighting file and it works well if there is only one file opened. However, if I do `:split otherFile`, the other buffer that gets opened does not have syntax highlighting. I have tried various things, like `:syntax on` etc. What can be the problem?

I am running Ubuntu 11.04, 64-bit version.

VIM version: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Mar 24 2011 07:07:34)

I have created a simple syntax highlighting file and put it in ~/.vim/plugin/syntax.vim

The last line of the syntax highlighting file is let b:current_syntax = "sth".
I haven't done any kind of wiring, like specifying the file location in .vimrc, the syntax works automatically (for one file opened).

Comment: You should include platform, version. How did you 'wire' the syntax to your filetypes? Is there an auto command?

Comment: I added some more descriptions to the text. Hope it clarifies the problem better.

Comment: What happens when you run `:set filetype?` on both of those 2 files?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently and much more generally. That is, the problem appeared for all filetypes. After debugging a bit, I discovered that the filetype was being properly recognized, but that for new splits, syntax was somehow becoming unset.

I'm still not 100% sure *how* this happened, but for future Google visitors, I'll write down what fixed the trouble for me: I moved `set syntax = on` much earlier in my `.vimrc`. After years of accretion, the line with `set syntax = on` had drifted down until it was below a number of other things. Moving it back up to (nearly) the top of the file fixed things for me. Here's what the start of my `.vimrc` looks like now:

```
" First two uncommented lines only useful if you use Tim Pope's vim-pathogen.  
" https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

" Most general settings first
set nocompatible            " Vim rather than Vi; implied by this file
syntax on                   " Syntax highlighting on
filetype plugin indent on   " Filetype detection

" ... etc.
```

Comment: Simple adding of `set nocompatible` fixed issue with lost filetypes for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting this, as I just observed the same behavior.  The solution that I found was to add the `filetype on` setting to my .vimrc file.  fwiw, I added it immediately after `syntax on`. `syntax on` happened to be at the top of my .vimrc file already.  So, here are the first few lines of my .vimrc:

```
1 " Activates Syntax Highlighting
2 syntax on
3 
4 " Filetype on
5 filetype on
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax files belong into `~/.vim/syntax/sth.vim`, not `~/.vim/plugin/syntax.vim`. The latter is sourced only once on startup, that's probably why it only works for the first loaded file.

For your syntax to become active, you need to `:setf sth`, or insert a corresponding modeline into your files, or write a filetype detection for your syntax to automate that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `syntax=on` was missing from `.vimrc`